# Inspecting and editing private/protected properties of objects

Tags: oop, matlab, private, protected

In MATLAB 2011b, I have some classes that have a number of private or protected class properties. This is by design, as I do not want these to be viewable, readable, writable, etc. by anything other than my class's own getters/setters.

However, there are times during development when I want to see what the state of these properties are. The class object is available to inspect in the workspace, but when I access the *Variable Editor* tool by double-clicking the object in the Workspace, none of the private/protected properties are visible.

I can understand that this is probably by design, but I'm hoping there is a setting I'm missing that will let me view them.

Comment: While a class is in development, I set all properties to public - I want to be able to see them all.

Comment: Why not set it to public when debugging?

Comment: Yes, setting to public works of course. It seems wrong to be to be required to do that simply to debug my code. In other languages (C, C++, etc.) the debugger has no qualms looking at private/protected variables. I'm just hoping for a convenient feature I'm overlooking.

Comment: @RyanEdwards: Turns out that the debugger has no qualms looking at private/protected variables in Matlab either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the attributes for debugging, then you can instead use the debugger to inspect the private/protected variables. For convenience, you can even write a method that gets you into the debugger, so that you don't have to manually set a stop:

```
classdef testObj_debug
    properties (Access=private)
        p1 = 4;
    end

    methods (Hidden)
        function checkProps(obj)
            keyboard
        end
    end
end
```

If you call `to = testObj_debug, to.checkProps`, you are accessing the debug mode, in which the hidden property `p1` is accessible and inspectable.

Comment: Fantastic trick using the checkProps method to drop into the object and snoop around. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway you know of where I could put the checkProps() method into a parent class and have it inherited by all of my classes? This would be a more convenient method of using this tool without needing to add it to every class I'm interested in.

Comment: @RyanEdwards: I have two major parent-classes: `myHandle` and `myValue`. They contain all the methods that I'd like every single class to have. For a handle class, I therefore write `classdef someHandleClass < myHandle` and for a subclass of `someHandleClass`, I write `classdef mySub < someHandleClass`, and everything gets inherited.

Comment: @Jonas, I tried your trick by putting a `checkProps` method in a base class and inheriting it with a derived class, but it appears that base class methods can't access private/protected members of derived classes. So as far as I can tell, the `checkProps` method has to be explicitly written into every class in which you want to use it. Does that jive with your understanding? I'm on Matlab 2014b (prerelease).

Comment: @DanielGolden: I'm a bit surprised that you wouldn't be able to access  these properties from an inherited function, but as long as the method works when you copy-paste it into other classes, I guess it does the job.